# DOA components uninstall in delphi

Tags: delphi, uninstallation, vcl, delphi-5

I am using Delphi version 5.0 and i have installed the DOA components for trial purpose. But now i want to remove it. Please help me to remove Direct Oracle Access(DOA) components. thanks for help.

Comment: How did you do the installation? With an installer or otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Head to [this](http://podgoretsky.com/ftp/Docs/Delphi/D5/dg/packcomp.html) page.

You will find extensive information on working with packages and components under Delphi 5.

**Installing component packages** is the section where you must delve into.

Comment: You are right. I am afraid we should consider the link as a dead one from now on.